# How to tell razor NOT to html escape

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using asp.net mvc 3 with razor for a project.
At some I need to serialize an array from the controller, put it in the viewdata and assign it to a js object. However when I output it using

```
@ViewData["some array"]
```

The result is html escaped so i get something like :

```
[{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Something&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;Something-1&quot; etc'
```

With the <%= %> this was not escaped so it was behaving as expected.
Is it possible to tell razor not to escape this string. Perhaps, someone might suggest another approach all together.

Thanks in advance for any ideas

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You need to output an instance of the new [`IHtmlString` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring.aspx), which contains pre-escaped HTML.

To do that write `@Html.Raw(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done everything and still issue persist while it was working earlier.. Better check Certificate Expiration Date.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30201717)