# How to Disable all security features from MVC

Tags: c#, security, model-view-controller

I'm developing a web Application on MVC Based and The way of my application work require me to disable all the security features which are build in with MVC.
Is there any way I can disable all of them ?

I need to know where is the code for each security feature.

The Application is actually for educational purpose to explain students how an attack can happen and i feel more comfortable by using MVC rather than classic ASP. 
Thank You !

Comment: What kind of security do you have in place? basically you can play with the pipeline in the startup file depending on what you have defined in there.

Comment: You have to write actual code in a bad way to have the security features disabled, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1110452/11683 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/4463265/11683. There is not much to disable configuration wise.